# why is ngModel causing crash?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ngmodel

I use `[(ngModel)]` in a `*ngFor`-Loop. But this produces an endless-loop and a crash of the browser.

this is my html:

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of controlSystemTargetViewModel.values; let index = index;">
      <div class="col" style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 0.5em;" >{{controlSystemTargetViewModel.values[index].assemblyType}}</div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name=sg{{index}} class="form-control" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0.5em;" [(ngModel)]="controlSystemTargetViewModel.values[index].key"  mdbInput>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is the type of the elements in values:

```html
import { ControlSystemTargetValueDto } from "src/app/api/models";

export class ControlSystemTargetValueViewModel {
    constructor(private dto: ControlSystemTargetValueDto) {
    }

    get assemblyType() : string {
        return this.dto.assemblyType; 
    }

    get key(): string {
        return this.dto.key;
    }

    set key(val : string) {
        this.dto.key = val; 
    }
}
```

`controlSystemTargetViewModel.values[index].assemblyType` will be shown. But when I add the `[(ngModel)]` to the input, I get the problem. I have used `item.key` first for binding the `ngModel`, but this is also not working. After some googleing, I have tried it with the index, but this is also not working. I hope, someone can help me to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="item.key"`

Comment: he did say he tried that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's an endless loop but if your array is very large and especially if it's updated often it could feel like an endless loop... you could try forcing angular to only update when you force it to.

In your ts file add

```
@Component({
    ...
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    ...
})
constructor( ... private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and then you can call this whenever your array gets populated or updated

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

I would suggest this anyways for performance reason when dealing with arrays

Comment: The Array has 14 entries.

Comment: I'm still not sure if i'd trust how ngModel tracks changes, expecially to a custom object. Have you breakpoint tested the infinite loop?

Comment: also since it's an input I'm pretty sure it won't work properly as you start typing... cause every keyboard/browser event that happens on that input field is gonna trigger angular to recheck everything, and this might trigger an ngModel refresh on the refocusing, which in turns would lead to rechecking everything... so there's your infinite loop possibly so yeah definitely do the OnPush strategy